# SELECT / GROUP BY - sequence of a value

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbltest (
  Col1           Integer(10) UNSIGNED,
  Col2           Integer(10) UNSIGNED
)
```

An there is the sample values:

```
Col1 Col2
---------
1     1   
2     1   
3     1   
4     1   
5     1   

6     2   
7     2   
8     2   
9     2   
10    2   

11    1   
12    1   
13    1   
14    1   
15    1
```

I want to `SELECT` `SUM(col1)` `GROUPBY` sequence values of col2  not by all values. With above data results is like this:

```
col1 col2 
---------
15    1   
40    2   
75    1
```

I don't have any idea how the query is looks like.
Also forgive me for this bad title. I don't know what it should be called.

Thanks

Comment: how you got 30 and 78? how can we understand without you describe?

Comment: Are you sure it's not *40*? (6.+7+8+9+10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a complex version due to the lack of analytic functions in MySQL; I'm assuming it's the `SUM` of `val1` you need;

```
SELECT SUM(val1) val1, MAX(val2) val2
FROM (
  SELECT s1.val1, COUNT(s3.val1) grouping, s1.val2 val2
  FROM sequence s1
  LEFT JOIN sequence s2 ON s1.val1 >= s2.val1
  LEFT JOIN sequence s3 ON s3.val1 = s2.val1 - 1 AND s2.val2 <> s3.val2
  GROUP BY s1.val1
) a
GROUP BY grouping
ORDER BY grouping
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d711/2).

If you add `grouping` to the selection list to make the order obvious, you get

```
val1    val2    grouping
15      1       0
40      2       1
65      1       2
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot. But it's so complicated. May you give me more info?

Comment: @SAMPro The inner select basically just row by row counts the preceding changes in `val2` (you can run the inner query by itself to see what it does), and the outer select groups by that change number to get the end result.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the SUM() function and GROUB BY.

So to get the answer you looking for

Closest I can get is without adding other columns:

```
SELECT SUM(val1) as total1, val2 FROM table_name
GROUB BY table_name.val2
```

Result:

```
total1 val2
---------
93    1
30    2
```

You might need to made a third column available that makes the three groups distinc such as

```
val1 val2 val3(new)
---------------
1    1   1
2    1   1
3    1   1
...  ..  ..
6    2   2
7    2   2
...  ..  ..
11   1   3
12   1   3
...  ..  ..
15   1   3
```

Then your SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT SUM(val1) as total2, val2 FROM table_name
GROUB BY table_name.val2, table_name.val3
```

Result:

```
total1 val2
---------
15    1
30    2
78    1
```

Referring to [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

Comment: Welcome and yeah,you right. But is there any solution that don't need thirds column?

Comment: Not without seperating the three groups another way. Looking at the data in your original table, the information is grouped 5 values each.  Is this something that is by accident like that, or on purpose?  If so you might be able to take advantage of knowing this about your dataset

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    select sum(val1) as val1, val2 from table1
    group by val2
```