# Laravel - Query Builder - Group by column value

Tags: php, laravel

I have the followind table:

```
Schema::create('rounds', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('color');
    $table->integer('random');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I need to return it grouped by color, but multiple groups, not only one of each color.

I tried to represent the way my array needs to be returned:

[image]

There are three colors and the grouping is represented by the color red.

As example I am using the first 6 items of the image. The first 6 items of the image should be formatted as follows:

```
[
  {
    "color": 4,
    "rounds": [
      {
        "random": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": 3,
    "rounds": [
      {
        "random": 32
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": 1,
    "rounds": [
      {
        "random": 56
      },
      {
        "random": 27
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": 4,
    "rounds": [
      {
        "random": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": 3,
    "rounds": [
      {
        "random": 32
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: so it will be looked like `[{"colors": "red", "items": [{...},..]}]`?

Comment: @BagusTesa Exactly!

Comment: seems need to write this kind [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28158276/4648586) but i cant think off how the query builder will be looked like.

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm terrible with `sql queries` =(

Comment: @CaioKawasaki could you provide a clearer example of how you need it to be grouped?

Comment: @HCK exactly like bagus comment

Comment: @CaioKawasakia i read his comment, but still isn't clear to me :/

Comment: @HCK now you can see an array on my question

Comment: @CaioKawasaki check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907090/7117697) answer. This should guide you in what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your table schema to:

```
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) { //renamed to groups for better understanding. See each set of randoms as one group having a color (3,4,etc)
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('color');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('rounds', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('group_id');
    $table->integer('random');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You will have to store it grouped to fetch it as a group.

Create a hasMany relation from groups to rounds.

Then, access data using:

Groups::orderBy('order')->with('rounds')->get();

Then a foreach for your groups in view.

Example entries in DB:
Groups table
[groups table sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqcAz.png)
Rounds table
[round table sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjBg8.png)

If you have records in order:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    public function randoms()
    {
        $allrows = DB::table('rounds')->get();
        $returnarray = [];
        $randoms = [];
        $thiscolor= false;
        foreach ($allrows as $row) {
            if ($row->color != $thiscolor) {
                $thiscolor = $row->color;//save current color reference
                if (isset($randoms['color'])) {//has value
                  $returnarray[] = $randoms;
                } // save previous value to jsonarray
                $randoms=[];//cleat $randoms
                $randoms['color'] = $row->color; // save color
                $randoms['rounds'][]['random'] = $row->random;//save this round
            } else {
                $randoms['rounds'][]['random'] = $row->random;//save round to previous color
            }
        }
        $returnarray[] = $randoms;
        return json_encode($returnarray);
    }
```

Comment: Will this keep multiple groups?

Comment: I have updated the answer with some sample from your json.

Comment: change the database is not an option =(

Comment: Are they stored in order in DB?

Comment: Yes they are stored in order

Answer (score 0):

Db query:

```
DB::table('rounds')
     ->select('*')
     ->groupBy('color')
     ->get();
```

Eloquent:

```
Rounds::select('*')
   ->groupBy('color')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Can't be this way, In the end I will have only 4 groups with yout query, and I need to have multiple groups...